# reading information for a specific gazebo model

Tags: gazebo, rostopic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi,
I'm using gazebo for simulating a quadrotor, in this world there's a plane, a light point and the quadrotor so when I type "rostopic echo /gazebo/model_states" I get pose and twist for all the models. Can someone tell me the right command to get pose and twist just for the quadrotor???

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/49537/reading-information-for-a-specific-gazebo-model/) by [schizzz8](https://answers.ros.org/users/3511/schizzz8/) on ROS Answers with karma: 183 on 2012-12-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Last time I looked into this, you could either get all model states via the "/gazebo/model_states" topic (as you suggested) or use the "/gazebo/get_model_state" service as described [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/simulator_gazebo/Tutorials/Gazebo_ROS_API), if you need information for a specific model. This service-based method probably isn't the nicest option if you have to retrieve the state at high updates rates, though.

If you're using the [hector_quadrotor](http://www.ros.org/wiki/hector_quadrotor) stack for simulation you're in luck though, as the ground truth pose is already provided on the "/ground_truth/state" topic through the use of the "libgazebo_ros_p3d.so" plugin. Corresponding gazebo xacro file [here](http://code.google.com/p/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/source/browse/fuerte/trunk/hector_quadrotor/hector_quadrotor_controller/urdf/quadrotor_sensors.urdf.xacro) (at the bottom).

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2012-12-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1